# Getting locations of JLabel added to JPanel

Tags: java, swing

I am working on a Java Application.

I am adding some labels after setting up the frame and making it visible.
I've also called `revalidate()` on the `JPanel`, on which I am adding the labels.

But, not all of the labels are returning correct position.

Here is my code.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();     
        JPanel view = new JPanel();
        view.setLayout(new MigLayout());
        scrollPane.setViewportView(view);
        frame.setContentPane(scrollPane);

        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        List<JComponent> labels = update(view);

        printLocations(labels);
    }

    public static List<JComponent> update(JPanel view) {
        view.removeAll();

        List<JComponent> labels = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            JLabel label = new JLabel("Label " + i);
            view.add(label);
            labels.add(label);
        }

        view.revalidate();
        view.repaint();

        return labels;
    }

    private static void printLocations(List<JComponent> labels) {
        for (JComponent label : labels) {
            System.out.println(label.getLocation());
        }
    }

}
```

Here is the output:

```
java.awt.Point[x=7,y=7]
java.awt.Point[x=52,y=7]
java.awt.Point[x=97,y=7]
java.awt.Point[x=0,y=0]
java.awt.Point[x=0,y=0]
java.awt.Point[x=0,y=0]
java.awt.Point[x=0,y=0]
java.awt.Point[x=0,y=0]
java.awt.Point[x=0,y=0]
java.awt.Point[x=0,y=0]
```

In this code, If I add some delay between updating and printing components' location, all components return correct position.
But, in my application, even delay is not working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, we must need to call `revalidate()` on the root component.
Then, this problem is solved.

In this example, root component is `frame`. So, the code will be as follows:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();     
        JPanel view = new JPanel();
        view.setLayout(new MigLayout());
        scrollPane.setViewportView(view);
        frame.setContentPane(scrollPane);

        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        List<JComponent> labels = update(view);

        frame.revalidate();

        printLocations(labels);
    }

    public static List<JComponent> update(JPanel view) {
        view.removeAll();

        List<JComponent> labels = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            JLabel label = new JLabel("Label " + i);
            view.add(label);
            labels.add(label);
        }

        view.repaint();

        return labels;
    }

    private static void printLocations(List<JComponent> labels) {
        for (JComponent label : labels) {
            System.out.println(label.getLocation());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `frame.revalidate();` == `JFrame.pack()` before `setVisible(true)`, then JFrame can returns all bounds or Dimension

Comment: List<JComponent> labels = update(view); after frame.setVisible(true); is called, you are in risk that JComponent are added to already visible JFrame, standard LayoutManager missing automatical notifier about, code is wrong designed or idea is wrong, sure depends of real idea, goal

Comment: @mKorbel So, all components should be added before frame.setVisible(true)?

Comment: So, all components should be added before frame.setVisible(true)? == not .........., sure its should be, but this logics, simple idea missing in code posted here (to show JFrame, start Swing Timer, add JComponents, refresing LayoutManager by revalidate and repaint), JComponents can returns own coordinates (to parent/container) only 1. after pack() is called or 2. JFrame/JDialog/JWindow is already visible on the screen